Pulling JSON in CLOB field
I have well formed JSON data that is held on a Oracle 11g table in a CLOB field.
CREATE TABLE INTERFACE_KAFKA_QUEUE
(
  AUDIT_NUMBER         NUMBER,
  MESSAGE              CLOB,
  DATE_INSERTED        DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
)

I would like to use the Kafka JDBC Connector to pull this JSON data from the table and send it to a Kafka topic.
The issue that I have is that when the JSON ends up on the topic it is a string and not a JSON object.
Does anyone know if it is possible to setup the connector and place the JSON as the payload on the topic and if it is possible, what the connector settings is?
I do not want to go and create a lot of extra moving parts or use KSQL to this.
EDIT:
The message that I end up with on the topic for the MESSAGE value is:
> "MESSAGE":
> "{\"BatchNumber\":\"861621\",\"InterchangeCount\":40,\"ActionType\":\"C\"}"

What I am looking for is for the message to be in this format on the topic.

"MESSAGE":
{"BatchNumber":"861621,"InterchangeCount":40,"ActionType":"C"}

This is my connector configuration:
name = [MY-CONNECTOR-NAME]
connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
errors.log.enable = true
errors.log.include.messages = true
connection.url = [MYDB-CONNECTION-STRING]
connection.user = [MYDB-USER]
connection.password = [MYDB-PASSWORD]
connection.attempts = 2
connection.backoff.ms = 10000
numeric.mapping = best_fit
dialect.name = OracleDatabaseDialect
mode = incrementing
incrementing.column.name = AUDIT_NUMBER
query = [MY-SQL-STRING]
topic.prefix = [MY-TOPIC]
principal.service.name = [MY-SERVICE-NAME]
principal.service.password = [MY-SERVICE-PASSWORD]


@OneCricketeer, thanks for your answer. I  have edited my original question with an example of what I would like on the topic. I have been speaking to a lot of people the last week and all of them suggested that I can only solve my problem using KSQL etc. It just feels like such an overhead if the data is already in my DB, I just need to move it t the topic.

You can move it to a topic... It'll just remain as bytes, not as json until you write an SMT

@OneCricketeer, I will try that.

JSON is a string. It is a notation, not a serialization format; UTF-8 is the serialization format.

and not a JSON object

The CLOB is just binary data. It should be base64 encoded on the topic. You would need to use Kafka Streams / ksqlDB to parse/decode base64 into an "object". Otherwise, you will have an object like
{"audit_number": 1, "message": "deadbeaf123", "date_inserted": "2024-11-15 01:02:03"}

vs
{"example": "this is your message"}

what the connector settings is

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConveter

For reading - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/
